# How to get the selected dates? in react calendar

Tags: reactjs

I downloaded react-native-material-calandarview inside my project.

They just give some piece of code to get calendar.
https://github.com/NuclleaR/react-native-material-calendarview.

I used that inside my render().
selectedDates={this.state.dates}......{this.state.dates} it gives undefined.
I need the selected dates array,but i cant get that.
where i get the selected dates???
Help me ASAP.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calendar expose you an event function `onDateChange`, you have just to setState in this event like that:

```
<Calendar
  selectedDates={this.state.dates}
  onDateChange={data => {
    // Add the data to your state here
    // for example:
    this.setState(state => { dates: state.dates.push(data.date) });
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks it works, 
onDateChange={data => { 
            this.state.selected_date=data.date;
            
        }}
But i used like this.
Now my doubt was, if i select datesSelection={'range'}, where it will give the selected dates